# Laravel doesn't recognize RegEx containing special character | or ]

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

I'm trying to check if a sentence contains the special character `|` or `]` using Laravel/Lumen validation in the controller like below:

```
'to_address' => 'required|max:200|regex:/^[^(|]~`!%^&*=};:?><’)]*$/',
```

If I user this validation on my controller, I'm getting the following error

```
{
    "error": "preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found"
}
```

Without `|` and `]` the validation is working correctly.

Comment: use this plain regex : [|\]]

Comment: See the **Note** in https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-regex

Comment: No, I'm getting the same error, I'm using the version of "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.7.*",

Answer (score 2):

Usually array of rules fixes this problem.

```
'to_address' => ['required', 'max:200', 'regex:/^[^(|]~`!%^&*=};:?><’)]*$/'],
```

Comment: getting same error for the special character ] the pipe character is fixed

Comment: You have an error in regular expression: "[" - 1 time, "]" - 2 times. Maybe, you need to backslash one of "]".

Comment: fixed as like this `'to_address' => ['required', 'max:200', 'regex:/^[^(|\\]~`!%^&*=};:?><’)]*$/'],`

Answer (score 0):

Both `|` and `]` are special characters in regular expressions, so you need to escape them with the `\` character:

```
'to_address' => 'required|max:200|regex:/^[^(\|\]~`!%^&*=};:?><’)]*$/',
```

If the pipe is supposed to be an `OR`, then you will need to use an array, as mentioned in [Laravel preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32810385/laravel-preg-match-no-ending-delimiter-found)

**Further reading:**

- [Regular Expression Reference: Special and Non-Printable Characters](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharacters.html)