# Laravel Regex Validattion - No ending delimiter '/' found

Tags: regex, laravel

I don't know why am receiving a:

> No ending delimiter '/' found`

[Here is a live sample](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/tnm)

Here is my regex validations

```php
$validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'cpf' => 'required|regex:/[0-9]{11}/',
    'identidade' => 'required|regex:/[0-9]{6,11}/'
]);
```

This one `regex:/[0-9]{11}/` is working fine;

But when I put a min delimiter `regex:/[0-9]{6,11}/` I get the error.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Try to  specify the rules in an array, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32810441/3832970).

Comment: Have you tried `/[0-9]{6,11}$/`

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Laravel are you using?
I'm using 5.8 and it is working fine.

But you can also try to use an array for the rules:

```
$validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [
   'cpf' => ['required', 'regex:/[0-9]{11}/'],
   'identidade' => ['required', 'regex:/[0-9]{6,11}/']
]);
```